# Docker on Ubuntu doesn't connect to localhost

Tags: docker, ubuntu, localhost

I have been going for hours trying to understand why docker just so happen to doesn't work on my machine. I am using Ubuntu 18.01 Xfce. Have installed docker using the official site and tried to test run an image using  `docker container run -it -p 8000:80 nginx` command. The first it ran ok, but only I try another time the localhost goes into an endless loop of loading. It only works after I restart docker and then only the first time. I also tried editing `docker.service` file into:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
```

as instructed on the `https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/` again no change.

Is there a solution to this problem? Is it and OS problem? Some kind of conflict problem? If so, is there a solution?

UPDATE:

This what `ip addr show docker0` command is showing when container is running:

```
5: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:4e:4b:8e:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::42:4eff:fe4b:8eaf/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

UPDATE 2:

By entering the commen `sudo docker run -t -i nginx /bin/bash` and reading the `tail -f /var/log/syslog` I have the following lines:

```
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX dockerd[8188]: time="2020-02-05T11:09:43.010897917+02:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX kernel: [ 1992.539911] docker0: port 2(vethb213531) entered disabled state
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX systemd-networkd[415]: vethb213531: Lost carrier
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX kernel: [ 1992.541590] veth4234a1c: renamed from eth0
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX systemd-timesyncd[994]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX systemd-udevd[9744]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX systemd-timesyncd[994]: Synchronized to time server 194.40.240.12:123 (194.40.240.12).
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1580893783.1724] manager: (veth4234a1c): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/43)
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX kernel: [ 1992.641548] audit: type=1107 audit(1580893783.171:310): pid=1164 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="DeviceAdded" name=":1.13" mask="receive" pid=3643 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=1280 peer_label="unconfined"
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX kernel: [ 1992.641548]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX kernel: [ 1992.644507] audit: type=1107 audit(1580893783.171:311): pid=1164 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.13" mask="receive" pid=3643 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=1280 peer_label="unconfined"
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX kernel: [ 1992.644507]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1580893783.1829] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth4234a1c, iface: veth4234a1c)
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1580893783.1830] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth4234a1c, iface: veth4234a1c): no ifupdown configuration found.
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX kernel: [ 1992.653532] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth4234a1c: link becomes ready
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX kernel: [ 1992.653779] docker0: port 2(vethb213531) entered blocking state
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX kernel: [ 1992.653784] docker0: port 2(vethb213531) entered forwarding state
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX networkd-dispatcher[1265]: WARNING:Unknown index 30 seen, reloading interface list
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX systemd-timesyncd[994]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1580893783.1911] device (veth4234a1c): carrier: link connected
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1580893783.1934] device (vethb213531): carrier: link connected
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX systemd-networkd[415]: veth4234a1c: Gained carrier
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX systemd-networkd[415]: vethb213531: Gained carrier
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX systemd-timesyncd[994]: Synchronized to time server 194.40.240.12:123 (194.40.240.12).
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX avahi-daemon[1159]: Interface vethb213531.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX avahi-daemon[1159]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface vethb213531.IPv6 with address fe80::c0e3:82ff:febc:a5c4.
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX kernel: [ 1992.746817] docker0: port 2(vethb213531) entered disabled state
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX kernel: [ 1992.753883] device vethb213531 left promiscuous mode
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX kernel: [ 1992.753893] docker0: port 2(vethb213531) entered disabled state
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX avahi-daemon[1159]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::c0e3:82ff:febc:a5c4 on vethb213531.
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1580893783.3453] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth4234a1c, iface: veth4234a1c)
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1580893783.3457] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethb213531, iface: vethb213531)
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX kernel: [ 1992.816316] audit: type=1107 audit(1580893783.343:312): pid=1164 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="DeviceRemoved" name=":1.13" mask="receive" pid=3643 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=1280 peer_label="unconfined"
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX kernel: [ 1992.816316]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1580893783.3528] device (vethb213531): released from master device docker0
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX systemd-networkd[415]: veth4234a1c: Lost carrier
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX systemd-timesyncd[994]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX systemd-networkd[415]: veth4234a1c: Removing non-existent address: fe80::42:acff:fe11:3/64 (valid forever), ignoring
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX systemd-networkd[415]: vethb213531: Lost carrier
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX systemd-timesyncd[994]: Synchronized to time server 194.40.240.12:123 (194.40.240.12).
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX dockerd[8188]: time="2020-02-05T11:09:43.530168634+02:00" level=warning msg="8f0463438568dab68c318d3fb928d800b9ca6ec99a918bb06bf8aea4886efa48 cleanup: failed to unmount IPC: umount /var/lib/docker/containers/8f0463438568dab68c318d3fb928d800b9ca6ec99a918bb06bf8aea4886efa48/mounts/shm, flags: 0x2: no such file or directory"
```

I only spotted these lines:

```
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX kernel: [ 1992.746817] docker0: port 2(vethb213531) entered disabled state
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX kernel: [ 1992.753883] device vethb213531 left promiscuous mode
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX kernel: [ 1992.753893] docker0: port 2(vethb213531) entered disabled state
```

And this line:

```
Feb  5 11:09:43 unkn0wn27-X550VX NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1580893783.3528] device (vethb213531): released from master device docker0
```

Not sure if that helps my case.

UPDATE 3:

A work around solution is to constantly write the command `sudo ip addr add 172.17.0.1/16 dev docker0`.

Comment: That modification to `docker.service` effectively makes unlimited root access available to any local process.  It's a massive security issue and you should undo it immediately.

Comment: What _is_ the problem you're encountering?  Can you include the actual error message you're getting or otherwise some sample output?  Can you include a relevant fragment of your application's source code?

Comment: That's the problem, no error is shown, and all I am doing is using this command `docker container run -it -p 8000:80 nginx`. Again, after restarting docker the first it works fine, but the second time docker shows that it is working but I can not access `localhost:8000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Docker not keeping it's IPV4 address.
All I had to do was open `/etc/systemd/network/mynet.network`, and add these 2 lines:

```
[Match]
Name=docker0

[Link]
Unmanaged=yes
```

Restart `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` and `systemctl restart docker`.

All credits for this solution found here: https://vadosware.io/post/a-reliable-fix-to-docker-not-keeping-its-ipv4-address-on-arch/