# Docker | docker0 has IP (is accessable from external) only at first run

Tags: docker, networking

When I start a simple docker container (e.g. Portainer) with

```
docker run -d --name portainer -p 9000:9000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock portainer/portainer
```

the container is accessable from the internet as expected.

When I stop (docker stop portainer) and start (docker start portainer) the container, the port 9000 is open again (verified with nmap), but the web interface of portainer loads forever.

```
# first run
networkctl

 IDX LINK            TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP      
   1 lo              loopback carrier     configured 
   2 enp35s0         ether    routable    configured 
   3 enp36s0         ether    no-carrier  configuring
   5 br-1815f2210327 bridge   no-carrier  configuring
   6 br-7f9b2f2637a1 bridge   no-carrier  configuring
   7 br-a9ae27884558 bridge   no-carrier  configuring
6552 br-39aac8ad8ef3 bridge   routable    configuring
6559 docker0         bridge   no-carrier  configuring

# next run
networkctl

 IDX LINK            TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP      
   1 lo              loopback carrier     configured 
   2 enp35s0         ether    routable    configured 
   3 enp36s0         ether    no-carrier  configuring
   5 br-1815f2210327 bridge   no-carrier  configuring
   6 br-7f9b2f2637a1 bridge   no-carrier  configuring
   7 br-a9ae27884558 bridge   no-carrier  configuring
6552 br-39aac8ad8ef3 bridge   no-carrier  configuring
6559 docker0         bridge   no-carrier  configuring
```

I already tried different workarounds that I found on the internet, like

```
nano /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

> {   "debug": true,   "bip": "172.20.0.1/16" }

and this config file in various configurations

```
nano /etc/systemd/network/docker0.network
```

> #[Match]
> #Name=docker0
>
> ```
> #[Network]
> #IPForward=yes
>
> #[Network]
> #Address=172.17.0.1/16
>
> #[Link]
> #Unmanaged=yes
> ```

(Currently everythings is commented out.)

When I restart the docker daemon with

```
systemctl restart docker
```

and then start the docker container

```
docker start portainer
```

it's working fine again.

My system is a linux root server hosted by strato.de:

```
docker -v
Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289

cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

uname -r
5.4.0-73-generic
```

The problem occurs with all of my docker containers on that server.

I would be very grateful for any further tips.

**UPDATE**

[Docker on Ubuntu doesn't connect to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60061583/docker-on-ubuntu-doesnt-connect-to-localhost)
The mentioned solution seems not work on my server with Ubuntu 20.04.

Yesterday I installed the same OS and docker version in a VM. Everything is working fine there.

Kind regards,
K1LLUM1N471

Answer (score 5):

My problem was that i could ping google only once in a container (`docker run --rm alpine ping google.com`), after exit it would not ping the next time i ran the same command. In `ifconfig docker0` the `inet` address was gone after exiting the container the `inet6` was still there after running the command once.

when running `networkctl status` the `docker0` link is at `configuring`.

This might do the trick:
the default Netplan config (`/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`)in my Ubuntu 22.04 server from Strato (dedicated server) is:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
      mainif:
        match:
          name: '*'
        dhcp4: yes
```

replace it with something like this:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
      enp3s0:
        dhcp4: yes
        dhcp6: no
      enp2s0:
        dhcp4: yes
        dhcp6: no
```

apply netplan config
`sudo netplan try` or `sudo netplan apply`

restart Docker
`sudo systemctl restart docker`

when now running `networkctl` the `docker0` link should be `unmanaged`

Comment: Thanks, that costed me 1+ days to fix. The update from Ubuntu 20 to 22 brought this "feature"

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much! I've spent more than that 1 day also on this issue! Any idea why this happening on Strato dedicated servers? Never had this issue before anywhere else...

Answer (score -1):

For your interrest:
I know that is not the best answer, but in my case I solved the problem by downgrading the OS on the root server :(

```
cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

docker -v
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
```